# How are PE Base Relocations build up?

Tags: executable, portability, relocation

I'm currently having trouble understanding how PE Base Relocations are build up.

I understand there can be more then one relocation, I understand also why and how this is done, but I just don't understand it programmatically:

Which of the following is true (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION in WinNT.h)?

```
// Base relocation #1
DWORD   VirtualAddress;
DWORD   SizeOfBlock; // size of current relocation
WORD    TypeOffset[1];
// Base relocation #2
DWORD   VirtualAddress;
DWORD   SizeOfBlock; // size of current relocation
WORD    TypeOffset[1];
// Base relocation #3
DWORD   VirtualAddress;
DWORD   SizeOfBlock; // size of current relocation
WORD    TypeOffset[1];
```

Or

```
DWORD   VirtualAddress;
DWORD   SizeOfBlock; // size of all relocations
WORD    TypeOffset[1]; // relocation #1
WORD    TypeOffset[1]; // relocation #2
WORD    TypeOffset[1]; // relocation #3
```

Or are both incorrect? How must I loop through all base relocations programmatically?

Currently I have this code, seems to be incorrect somewhere:

```
DWORD baseRelocationSize = imageNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].Size;
            unsigned int baseRelocationCount = baseRelocationSize / sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION);
            DWORD baseDelta = (DWORD_PTR)moduleBase - (DWORD_PTR)imageNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

            IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION* baseRelocation = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION*)((DWORD_PTR)moduleBase + (DWORD_PTR)imageNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress);

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i != baseRelocationCount; ++i)
            {
                unsigned int entryCount = (baseRelocation->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);

                for(unsigned int j = 0; j != entryCount; ++j)
                {
                    WORD* entry = (WORD*)((DWORD_PTR)baseRelocation + (DWORD_PTR)sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION));
                    if((*entry >> 12) & IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW)
                    {
                        DWORD* pdw = (PDWORD)((DWORD_PTR)moduleBase + (DWORD_PTR)baseRelocation->VirtualAddress + ((*entry) & 0xfff));
                        (*pdw) += baseDelta;
                    }

                    entry++;
                }

                baseRelocation += baseRelocation->SizeOfBlock;
            }
```

Comment: It's a tricky one, right?

Comment: Relocations are ridiculous, nobody seems to know the correct way to handle them.

Comment: @JohnSmith did you figure this out?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Neither options you indicated entirely correct/true.

This excellent tutorial on [How to inject code in a PE file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12532/Inject-your-code-to-a-Portable-Executable-file#ImplementRelocationTable7_2) shows that the actual `IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION` structure is:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION {
  DWORD   VirtualAddress;
  DWORD   SizeOfBlock;
} IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION, *PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION;
```

Section 5.2 of this [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v83.docx) describe the structure. The `SizeOfBlock-8` actually indicates how many `WORD TypeOffset` follow after the `VirtualAddress` and `SizeOfBlock`.

I think you would also be interested in Table 7 of the tutorial, which shows the structure of the blocks from the relocation table. I'll copy-paste the table here for quick-reference.

[image]

Comment: This is just perfect. One last question, how do you know how many blocks there are?

Comment: The number of block is not written anywhere. What I do is go block by block until the current address is equal to `imageNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress + imageNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].Size` at this point you know that you're at the end of the `.reloc` section

Comment: Just to be 100%, when you say `"The SizeOfBlock-8 actually indicates how many WORD TypeOffset follow after the VirtualAddress and SizeOfBlock"` you should say `"The (SizeOfBlock-8) / sizeof(WORD) actually indicates how many WORD TypeOffset follow after the VirtualAddress and SizeOfBlock"`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I checked the link you posted. Really the best description i found on the internet. Though i have one question. If i got the asm part inside the link right, the sizeOfBlock field includes the padding 00 00 in the end of the block right? Eventhough its not really an entry. Furthermore the 00 00 part only exists to pad the array of entries to 32bit and thus does not have to exist in every block right?

Answer (score 5):

from some code.. aldo check out reactos :)

```
BOOL FixRelocs(void *base, void *rBase, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *ntHd, IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION *reloc,
               unsigned int size) {
    unsigned long ImageBase = ntHd->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
    unsigned int nBytes = 0;
    unsigned long delta = MakeDelta(unsigned long, rBase, ImageBase);
    unsigned long *locBase;
unsigned int numRelocs;
unsigned short *locData;
unsigned int i;

while(1) {
  locBase =
     (unsigned long *)GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD)(reloc->VirtualAddress), ntHd, (PBYTE)base);
  numRelocs = (reloc->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);

  if(nBytes >= size) break;

  locData = MakePtr(unsigned short *, reloc, sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION));
  for(i = 0; i < numRelocs; i++) {       
     if(((*locData >> 12) == IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW))
         *MakePtr(unsigned long *, locBase, (*locData & 0x0FFF)) += delta;
     locData++;
  }

  nBytes += reloc->SizeOfBlock;
  reloc = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION *)locData;
   }

   return TRUE;

}
```