# Is it a GDB bug or Intel Compiler bug or my code?

Tags: c, gdb, intel

I am using Intel's ICC compiler for NetBSD systems. I have been fighting with a bug, and got surprised even more when I observed that from the core dump - address of a symbol from two different mechanisms in gdb are not same.

The variable connection_out seems to have different address when checked with "info symbol connection_out" and p &connection_out.

Does it looks like a compiler problem where badf_errcnt which was optimized into CPU registers, is assigned a memory location, and thereafter compiler got confused between two ?

I have compiler O2 level optimizations ON.
The variable in question is a global static int variable.
I don't think pointer aliasing is in its role here as the variable's memory location is being used.

I see the unstripped symbol file also concurs the address in the disassembled code.

```
gdb$ disassemble sigusr1_rt
Dump of assembler code for function sigusr1_rt:
   0x01845000 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x01845001 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x01845003 <+3>:     sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x01845006 <+6>:     movl   $0x16c156a,0x188f05c
   0x01845010 <+16>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x01845012 <+18>:    pop    %ebp
   0x01845013 <+19>:    ret    
   0x01845014 <+20>:    lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
   0x0184501a <+26>:    lea    0x0(%edi),%edi
End of assembler dump.
gdb$ info symbol 0x188f05c
connection_out in section .bss of /sites/eqx/work/swcores/tripunjay/F10ACOREDIR/f10cp_sshd.login-eqx-06.6402/sshd
gdb$ p &connection_out
$10 = (int *) 0x188f048
gdb$ p/d 0x188f05c - 0x188f048
$11 = 20
gdb$ p/x 0x188f05c - 0x188f048 
$12 = 0x14
gdb$ info symbol 0x188f048
badf_errcnt.5450.0.13 in section .bss of /sites/eqx/work/swcores/tripunjay/F10ACOREDIR/f10cp_sshd.login-eqx-06.6402/sshd
gdb$ p &badf_errcnt
No symbol "badf_errcnt" in current context.
gdb$ select-frame 5
gdb$ frame         
Stack level 5, frame at 0xbb4aca20:
 eip = 0x1846007 in wait_until_can_do_something (serverloop.c:404); saved eip 0x1846698
 called by frame at 0xbb4b0af0, caller of frame at 0xbb4ac9d0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xbb4aca18, args: readsetp=0xbb4b0ab4, writesetp=0xbb4b0ab8, maxfdp=0x4, nallocp=0xbb4b0abc, max_time_milliseconds=0x0
 Locals at 0xbb4aca18, Previous frame's sp is 0xbb4aca20
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xbb4aca00, ebp at 0xbb4aca18, esi at 0xbb4ac9fc, edi at 0xbb4aca04, eip at 0xbb4aca1c
readsetp = 0xbb4b0ab4
writesetp = 0xbb4b0ab8
maxfdp = 0x4
nallocp = 0xbb4b0abc
max_time_milliseconds = 0x0
badf_errcnt = <optimized out>
tv = <optimized out>
tvp = <optimized out>
client_alive_scheduled = 0x0
gdb$ p &badf_errcnt
Can't take address of "badf_errcnt" which isn't an lvalue.


prompt$ nm sshd.unstripped | grep connection_out   
0188f05c b connection_out
```

Comment: I see the same address with info and p being shown. Where is the different address?

Comment: There are two addresses - info symbol 0x188f05c shows connection_out while p &connection_out shows 0x188f048 AND info symbol 0x188f048 shows another variable

Comment: are you using the platform gdb or intel's special gdb build?

Comment: I don't know what exactly the tools do and I don't recognize a known pattern in the flood of numbers. But addresses created by compiler may be different from addresses used at runtime because of the image displacement introduced by [executable file loader](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial). Without understanding any details I would vote for "_or my code_" and arranging **code review** session with your coworkers (1 to 3) should be the easy way out

Comment: I am sorry. Did not understand that.  Are you saying that the address in the disassembled code,  which obviously was generated by compiler, is not the real address to be used while executing code ? And then that means the address as shown by gdb is the correct address,  right?

Comment: @RIPUNJAYTRIPATHI at least on Windows this is absolutely true. A symbol placed by the compiler at offset 2300 and hard coded into the library binary file can be at rutime once at 2300+XY1 or at 2300+XY2 or at.. where XY is the address which was free when OS tried to map the library into memory. Its [complete magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436668/how-are-pe-base-relocations-build-up) and this [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) must be taken into account. I don't know if it applies to `gdb`+`linux` as well but on Windows the numbers are different

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a possible bug in ICC-generated debug info, or in the linker.

In particular, it appears that address of `connection_out` in the symbol table does not match the address of `connection_out` in the `.debug_info`.

To find `&connection_out` in symbol table, do this:

```
readelf -Ws /sites/.../f10cp_sshd.login-eqx-06.6402/sshd |
  grep connection_out
```

and compare with output from

```
readelf -wi /sites/.../f10cp_sshd.login-eqx-06.6402/sshd
```

which should have an entry for `connection_out`, that will be similar to this:

```
<1><b6>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <b7>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x84): connection_out 
    <bb>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
    <bc>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5        
    <bd>   DW_AT_type        : <0x73>   
    <c1>   DW_AT_external    : 1        
    <c1>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 60 10 60 0 0 0 0 0       (DW_OP_addr: 601060)
```

If the address in the symbol table differs from the address in `.debug_info` (the `DW_AT_location` entry), you have a compiler (or linker) bug. If they are the same, you have a GDB bug.

Comment: In the second command readelf -wi, I did not get any address, while I get an address in the previous one (readelf -Ws).  :   DW_AT_name        : connection_out